# How can I configure Spring Secuirty to allow authenticated users (having specific authorities) to connect to my web socket?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am working on a Spring Boot project implementing a web socket but I have some problem trying to call it from the external. This problem should be caused by a Spring Security configuration issue.

I started by this example (that doesn't contains Spring Security): https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-websocket

This is what I have done: first of all I have implemented this **WebSocketConfig** class implementing the **WebSocketConfigurer** interface:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/deposit-notification");
    }

}
```

So this web socket is listening on the **/deposit-notification** path of my Spring Boot.

Then I have implement the actual web socket by this class **SocketTextHandler** extending **TextWebSocketHandler**:

```
@Component
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        String payload = message.getPayload();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(payload);
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hi " + jsonObject.get("user") + " how may we help you?"));
    }

}
```

Then, in order to test it, I have the **index.html** file and the related JQuery script shown in the previous tutorial link.

As you can see the **app.js** contains the JQuery script that perform the websocket connection:

```
var ws;
function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);
}

function connect() {
    console.log("Into connect()");
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8019/deposit-notification');
    ws.onmessage = function(data) {
        helloWorld(data.data);
    }
    setConnected(true);
}

function disconnect() {
    if (ws != null) {
        ws.close();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Websocket is in disconnected state");
}

function sendData() {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'user' : $("#user").val()
    })
    ws.send(data);
}

function helloWorld(message) {
    $("#helloworldmessage").append(" " + message + "");
}

$(function() {
    $("form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#connect").click(function() {
        connect();
    });
    $("#disconnect").click(function() {
        disconnect();
    });
    $("#send").click(function() {
        sendData();
    });
});
```

As you can see here it try to perform the connection:

```
function connect() {
    console.log("Into connect()");
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8019/deposit-notification');
    ws.onmessage = function(data) {
        helloWorld(data.data);
    }
    setConnected(true);
}
```

In my case the execution of the connection is not working, in the Chrome console I obtain this error message:

```
app.js:9 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8019/deposit-notification' failed:
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is related to a Spring Security missconfiguration because if I disable Spring Security it works fine (I can perfectly use the example provided in the previous tutorial).

and into the STS stacktrace Spring is giving me the following error message:

```
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.550[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /deposit-notification
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.550[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.550[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.551[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /deposit-notification] with attributes [hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','CLIENT')]
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.551[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.551[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.552[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /error
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.552[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.552[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.552[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /error
[2m2022-02-18 12:11:01.555[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

I was trying to understand this log, basically it is trying to perform a **GET** call toward the defined "/deposit-notification" but this filder fails:

```
Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /deposit-notification] with attributes [hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','CLIENT')]
```

This seems reasonable because my Spring Security configuration involves the use of JWT token and I have put this resource into the matcher of users having **ADMIN** or **CLIENT** authorities (this because I want that this web socket is used only by authetniocated users having these authorities). My JQuery script is not passing any JWT token so I think that this error is pretty normal.

Exist a way to pass the JWT token also when I call for a web socket like this from JQuery?

Anyway I am absolutly not sure that this is the correct way to configure Spring Security and web sockets.

Anyway this is my Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    private static final String[] USER_MATCHER = { "/api/users/email/**"};
    private static final String[] ADMIN_MATCHER = { 
                                                        "/api/users/email/**",
                                                        "/api/admin/**"
                                                        /*
                                                        "/api/admin/users/**",
                                                        "/api/admin/usertype/**",
                                                        "/api/admin/coin/**",
                                                        "/api/admin/wallet/**"
                                                        */
                                                   };

    private static final String[] COMMON_MATCHER = {
            "/api/admin/user/{id}/wallet",
            "/deposit-notification"
    };
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception 
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }   
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /*
         * NOTE:
         * Using hasRole expects the authority names to start with 'ROLE_' prefix
         * Instead, we use hasAuthority as we can use the names as it is
         */
        http.csrf().disable()
                   .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers(USER_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("CLIENT")
                    .antMatchers(COMMON_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CLIENT")
                   .antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                   .antMatchers("/api/users/test").authenticated()
                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().denyAll()
                   .and()
                   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(
            new TokenVerificationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, jwtTokenUtil),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
    /* To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) 
    {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",
                                    "/webjars/**",
                                    "/v2/**",
                                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                                    "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };

}
```

As you can see here I have

```
private static final String[] COMMON_MATCHER = {
        "/api/admin/user/{id}/wallet",
        "/deposit-notification"
};
```

and then I set both the **ADMIN** and **CLIENT** authorities for this:

```
.antMatchers(COMMON_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CLIENT")
```

I also tried to allow not authenticated connection to the previous **/deposit-notification** "endpoint" chainging my **configure()** method in this way:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    /*
     * NOTE:
     * Using hasRole expects the authority names to start with 'ROLE_' prefix
     * Instead, we use hasAuthority as we can use the names as it is
     */
    http.csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(USER_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("CLIENT")
               .antMatchers(COMMON_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CLIENT")
               .antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
               .antMatchers("/api/users/test").authenticated()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/deposit-notification").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().denyAll()
               .and()
               .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(
        new TokenVerificationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, jwtTokenUtil),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

As you can see i added this matcher:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/deposit-notification").permitAll()
```

in this case I obtain this error in the STS stacktrace:

```
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.019[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.020[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.025[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 4 ms
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.026[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /deposit-notification
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.026[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.026[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.027[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Authorized filter invocation [GET /deposit-notification] with attributes [permitAll]
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.027[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /deposit-notification
[2m2022-02-18 12:22:12.031[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m18080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-1][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

it doesn't work but anyway it is not a good solution because I don't want to allow that everybody can connect to this websocket (I want that only authenticated users having **ADMIN** or **CLIENT** authorities can connect).

**EDIT-1:** After creating a **WebSocketSecurityConfig** extending **AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer** as shown here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html#websocket-configuration

```
package com.easydefi.users.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
                .nullDestMatcher().authenticated() 
                .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/deposit-notification").permitAll() 
                .anyMessage().denyAll(); 

    }
}
```

The problem now is that running my Spring Boot application I obtain this error message in the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.easydefi.users.GetUserWsApplication.main(GetUserWsApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@12bb4df8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:371) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3334) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2446) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
    ... 43 common frames omitted

[2m2022-02-18 13:51:45.132[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m21385[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@12bb4df8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:371) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:874) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:348) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.easydefi.users.GetUserWsApplication.main(GetUserWsApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3334) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2446) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

What is wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you implement `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` like it is explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html#websocket-configuration)?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I have tried it now after your response but now I obtain an exception. I put all the information at the end of my original post

Comment: It seems that the `spring-security-messaging` dependency is missing

Comment: after that I added it I obtain this error message: APPLICATION FAILED TO START A component required a bean named 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' that could not be found. Consider defining a bean named 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' in your configuration.

Comment: just as a side note, the tutorial you are referring to uses spring 1.4.1 which was released 21 of september, 2016 current version of spring boot is 2.6.3 (at the time of writing) a lot has changed since then.